# Complete using match in middle of string - work with pop-up list?

Tags: completion, company-mode, auto-complete-mode, completing-read

I'm trying to use auto-complete to match in the *middle* of a string (after the characters `::`). I'd like to typing `a` then hit tab and have the list of candidates appear 'in full' e.g. `fruit::apples`, `others::apples`, `veg::asparagus`.

So far, I'm approaching this using an alist:

```
(setq l1 '(("apples"  "fruit::apples")
       ("apples"  "other::apples")
       ("bananas"  "fruit::bananas")
       ("asparagus"  "veg::asparagus")))
```

The completions are matched to the `car` of each element in `l1` but return the `cdr`. The 'prefix' part always ends with `::` and I would prefer to avoid using alternatives such as `fruit-apples`...

Here is a function which prompts in the minibuffer and can display a list of candidates in another window:

```
(defun f1 () "
Replaces text at point with completion, including the appropriate prefix"
       (interactive)
       ;; ac1 = all completions
       ;; lc1 = list of completions
       (let ((tap1 (thing-at-point 'symbol))
         ac1
         (lc1 ())
         (resize-mini-windows t)
         (p1 (point))
         elem1 r1)
     (when (not tap1) (set 'tap1 ""))
     (set 'ac1 (all-completions tap1 l1))
     (mapc (lambda (elem1)
         (when (member (car elem1) ac1)
           (push (cdr elem1) lc1)))
           l1)
     (set  'lc1 (mapcar (lambda (x) (print (car x))) lc1))
     (set 'elem1 (concat "Complete " tap1 " (TAB for selection) : "))
     (set 'r1 (completing-read elem1 lc1))
     (delete-region (- p1 (length tap1)) p1)
     (insert r1)))
```

so that if I call `f1` when at text that says `a` I can replace it as desired.

Now, is there any way to adapt [auto-complete](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) to behave like this? I've been going through the source files and can't figure out where I should replace the usual list of `(all-completions STRING COLLECTION)` with the list which includes the prefixes.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Should I be looking at [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Even with vanilla Emacs you can do this, just by using `completing-read` and looking up the car in `I1`. If the cars are unique then `assoc` is all you need.

```
(cadr (assoc (completing-read "Choose: " I1) I1))
```

Comment: Sorry, the `car`s are not unique here; I have edited the question to reflect this. Good suggestion though.